# sum of conditionally independent Bernoulli variables on a bayesian network

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, bayesian-network, bernoulli-distribution

I constructed a Bayesian network which presents the conditional independence
among N random variables. Each random variable $X_i$ represents a Bernoulli random
variable with an associated success probability $\pi$ (the probabilities, $\pi$`s, are
the parameters of the Bayesian graph).

I'm interested in computing the sum $S=X_1+X_2+...+X_N$. This means I'm interested in computing the sum over the nodes of the Bayesian graph. I know that Bayesian graph enables us to compute the joint
probability distribution $p(X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_N)$ but not their sum.

Are there some references or ideas that deal with the same sum on a Bayesian graph.

I found this page [Decomposing dependent Bernoulli random variables into independent Bernoulli random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230930/decomposing-dependent-bernoulli-random-variables-into-independent-bernoulli-rand?rq=1)

Can some one tell whether we can use this link to compute the sum $S$.

Comment: More specifically, I'm looking to find out the probability distribution of p(S=k) or its argmax. For independent bernoulli variables, this distribution is called poisson's binomial distribution. However, when there are conditional independence and dependence among variables (modeled using the bayesian graph), I don't know how to find out this distribution.

Comment: why don't you just create a new deterministic node $S=\sum_i X_i$ in your network. Then you can sample from it using MCMC, Gibbs etc. Or even do exact inference on it.

Comment: thanks YBE for your answer, but for now I don't see what you mean exactly.

Comment: thanks YBE for your answer.  Sorry, I didn't find the details how your suggestion works. Please note that I need to estimate/predict the value of S before getting its exact value from the experiment. Means, I will not wait the result of the trials in order to compute S. I want to quantify S given the success probabilities on the Bayesian graph.

Comment: You have Bayes net with variables X1,..., XN right? What I am saying is introduce an additional node to your Bayes Net, which is the S you defined in your question. Then just using whatever inference routine you are utilizing; compute the joint posterior p(X1,...,XN,S). Then you can marginalize if you just want p(S).

Comment: I will try to do it. Do you have some references or links that can provide more details. I didn't use deterministic node, before, to compute sum of the other nodes in a Bayes network.

Comment: I am looking for a good basic to intermediate paper that uses the solution proposed by YBE. I have a computer science background and basic Bayesian knowledge.

Comment: Do you want to do things by hand? Any probabilistic programming language will handle such things automatically.

Comment: Sorry YBE. These are may be trivial things for you, but I'm very new to the area. So , that is why I'm not familiar with all what you have said.

Comment: no worries, is this a homework question where you are expected to do computations by hand or is this is a project where you would like to do inference via computers since the model is big? I am just trying to understand your requirement.

Comment: This is a project. I would like to do inference via computer (software), the model is quite big.

Comment: Probabilistic programming language (PPL) is a high-level programming language where you can define your probabilistic model and use available black-box inference engines like MCMC, Gibbs, Variational Inference etc. Some famous alternatives are: [BUGS](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/), [STAN](http://mc-stan.org/), Church, Anglican etc.

Comment: Ok. which free software for windows that uses PPL do you recommand ?

Comment: STAN seems the best bet.

Comment: Ok, thanks YBE, I installed STAN with software R. Now, to construct the graph model, I plan to use Bayesian Network Constraint-Based Structure Learning Algorithms (like PC and IC) with some modifications. Is PC algorithm already implemented in STAN ?

Comment: However, still I don't see how to get sum S of X1+X2+...XN? In fact, using your suggestion mean S will be a node in the graph:
1)  What are the parents of S? If I suppose their parents are all the Xi, so I need to define relations among Xi given S. ?
2)  Each Xi is a bernoulli random variable, its parameter pi represents conditional probability distribution of that node (random variable). Hwvr, I need the binary value of Xi not its parameter pi. 
==> I think a deterministic node is not enough to compute S. I think it should be some way to quantify dependence among the Xi random variables .

Comment: in your question you said: "I constructed a Bayesian network". Ideally that network encodes all the dependence/independence information over Xi's. I am just telling you to add a node variable S whose parents are all the Xi's with the conditional density $p(S|X1,...,XN)=\delta(S-(X1+\dots+XN))$.
You do not need to define relations among Xi given S, that's the job of the inference engine. You define a forward generative model respecting the causality and then do inference on it.
A bernoulli variable takes values 0 or 1 in your model.